# Child behavior when hovered should diverge from child behavior when hovering on parent element

Tags: css

I would like to prescribe a behavior for a child element when hovering on its parent, and a different behavior when hovering on the child element itself. In my example, the property is border color.

How can this be done without the use of the `!important` (see SCSS code below)?

```
<div class="filetile">
  <div class="filename">
    foo
  </div>
  <div class="fileTile-menu">
    <div class="gear-icon">
      <img src="https://sslbucket-a.akamaihd.net/gears.opswat.com/marketing-site/icon_menu.png"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.filetile {
  height: 30px;
  width: 110px;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-table;
  &:hover {
    background-color: #efeeb3;
    > .fileTile-menu {
      border: 1px solid #646464;
    }
  }
}

.filetile > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.fileTile-menu {
  float: right;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  &:hover {
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5 !important;
  }
}
```

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/pgblu/pen/mJxLrr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place your .fileTile-menu rule within the scss-rule of the .filetile: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNMreX

```
.filetile {
  height: 30px;
  width: 110px;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #333333;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-table;
  &:hover {
    background-color: #efeeb3;
    > .fileTile-menu {
      border: 1px solid #646464;
    }
  }

 .fileTile-menu {
   float: right;
   padding: 3px;
   border: 1px solid transparent;
   &:hover {
     border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
   }
 }
}
```

Why does it work this way? Your scss compiler will evaluate your scss to following rules:

```
.filetile {...}
.filetile:hover {...}
.filetile:hover > fileTile-menu { border : 1px solid #646464;}
.filetile .fileTile-menu { border : 1px solid transparent;}
.filetile .fileTile-menu:hover { border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;}
```

Through this change you gain the specificity you will need to achieve what you aim for. To learn more about specificity take a look at this article: [CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)